# Batch Removing Broken Images from Magento

Tags: error, import, product-images, delete

We just had a team mass import about 2500 products to our magento store and the only way they could do it from Zen Cart's Image Handler 2 plugin was to import 4 images for each product even if the product only had 2 images on zen cart. So that leaves 1000's of products with unnecessary broken images.

Is there any way to batch remove these? Any kind of plugin or tool? You'll have to excuse me, I'm a ui guy and don't know much about the backend.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ryaan-anthony/9c3ffc3d75dc9c754f3d I see this but I have no idea how I would use it or if that's what I'm looking for

Comment: I think I'd find another "team". Your link above should work, just drop that script into a file in your root install, and run it

Comment: Thanks Tim. Finding someone to handle Image Handler 2 and zen cart was not easy, I went through about 10 people that tried and failed.

Comment: Once this http://marketlark.com launches that sort of thing will be cake